# Crawling large amount of dynamic data

Tags: web-crawler

I am crawling a dynamic website like imdb. Here I am interested in crawling certain elements like the rating of the movie and the number of users who have voted. However imdb is a dynamic site. The news keeps changing every few mins. I am not interested in crawling through all the data. In my initial crawl I have scraped the whole site. Now I am interested in how a few div elements changes. For instance think about the ratings. Do I need to crawl the whole site every time and query it against my database to check whether the elements have changed? There are no scope for rss/atom feeds. How can I solve this problem without crawling through the whole site and building my database all over again.

Comment: How are you crawling ? Are you parsing the HTML content ? You could try to study the website to see if they use POST requests returning JSON (very unlikely since every genius on the planet would be able to easily use it, but I found some sites doing so). I think you will need to parse every pages everytime you want an update. Sometimes you can negotiate an API access for an acceptable price.

Comment: Oh and an idea I had some times ago was to use my users as parsers. They would go to my page, and then launch a request to the other site, getting back the results and transmitting them to me for an update: I would get only the most popular stuff and not everything. Could work if you build a meta-imdb site for example. You can do that by integrating an iframe and doing a few JS stunts.

Comment: Yes I will be parsing the HTML content."I think you will need to parse every pages everytime you want an update" - This is the very thing I want to avoid as it would be a lot of overhead as I am dealing with nearly 15 GB of data. Parsing that every time could be costly. And similarly wouldn't API calls be costly too?

Comment: "They would go to my page, and then launch a request to the other site, getting back the results and transmitting them to me for an update" - I thought along the similar lines too but again for the first user querying something, launching the request time live would take lots of time wouldn't it?

Comment: API calls would be costly indeed. What about using the website as a dynamic data source instead of storing it ? Your users make a request, you transfer this request into a complex wrapped request to the foreign site, retrieving live the results for your users.

Comment: Yeah it would take some times, but again either you synchronize with the site somehow and you need to access their data exactly, or you use the site as if it was your database, but that would have all sort of slowdowns, new protections after a few weeks etc. I parsed some of my gov sites and made some close for a few days, I fear it's the usual stuff in site crawling.

Comment: well yes live API calls are always there but would they be the best choice? I believe there are many problems associated with that. Apart from the increased overhead time, if too many requests occur from the same API key, webmasters tend to block API access for that key. I am building something heavy here!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47596/discussion-between-pierre-and-sarkar)